# Why is undefined returned when accessing properties of a typescript object in an angular2 project?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular2 project in which I am using the http module to make a get request. The object is retrieved from the server and apparently is deserialized properly into its corresponding typescript object, but when I try to access a property it returns undefined, even though when I print the object to the console right before trying to access these properties, the data appears to exist.

This is what my get request method looks like.

```
  getDataForEmployee(data){
    var url = this.active+"/guest/"+data;

    var headers = new Headers();

    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.http
      .get(url, {headers:headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then((res:Response)=> res.json() as Employee);

  }
```

This is how the method looks which is handling the response.

```
this.employeeHttp.getDataForEmployee(userid)
  .then((employee:Employee)=>{
    console.log(employee);
    console.log("firstname: "+employee.firstName);
    ...
```

The Employee class looks like this:

```
 export class Employee {

    ...
      private _firstName:string;
    ...

      get firstName(): string {
        return this._firstName;
      }

      set firstName(value: string) {
        this._firstName = value;
      }

    ...
    }
```

The image shows the console output when making this request.
[image: Image of the console output]

I don't understand why when I try to retrieve firstName it returned undefined even though it exists in the object right before.

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be very helpful to me.

Comment: in the screenshot i see _firstName did u try console.log("firstname: "+employee._firstName);

Comment: Also, unrelated, but GET requests don't have a content (body), so sending a Content-Type header makes no sense.

Comment: @Dhyey I have tried that, which works, but I dont like doing that, because then I have to set the property as a public property, which means that I am accessing the property directly instead of using the getters and setters which seems like the proper way of interacting with typescript objects.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the tip

Comment: @Dan when you receive an object from AJAX response it is a simple JSON string converted to javascript object. It doesn't have getters and setters i.e it is not a class just simple data

Comment: @Dhyey yes, but to my understanding, and what I want to happen is for angular to take this JSON object and deserialize it into a typescript object which I have defined.

Comment: @Dhyey I have uploaded what the Employee class looks like defined in typescript

Comment: after the get I would try .map((response:Response) =>{ response.json(): Employee})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are expecting can be achieved only by inheritance. But declaring a type of an object as a class doesn't make the object inherit the class i.e `employee` is not a child of `Employee` in your code.

To call the getter you will have to inherit it first eg:

```
let emp = new Employee("Dan"); // passing only firstName for demo
```

Then you will be able to access `emp.firstName` and it will return `Dan`. You will also need to accept arguments in your `Employee` class.

I have made a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/L7BpqCjIlcAd5uDaAguY?p=preview) demo where the `Employee` class accepts one argument for firstName. Keep your developer tools open so that it will stop in both getter and setter.

As typescript only checks code at compile type you have no way of checking  if the API returned something else eg: `_name` instead of `_firstName` at runtime. So I recommend using an `interface` instead of a `class` in your case.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is helpful.