# (Angular 2/4) How to remove an object from the local storage value which is an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, local-storage

I am trying to delete the item when the remove button is clicked.

I tried to find the item's index of the array and use the function Splice. No luck yet.

I was able to access to the item that's clicked but not the property _title which is a private variable in the todo model. I was going to map through array with the title but the _title was returned as 'undefined'.

I don't think localStorage.removeItem is a valid option since everything is stored in the value.

Anyway I am really lost at this point. I would appreciate any help!

**tl;dr How can I get either the item's index # or _title which is a private variable in the model?**

The local storage looks like this:

Key - STORAGE_ITEM_NAME

Value - 
[{"_completed":false,"_title":"Create a Todo App"},{"_completed":false,"_title":"Debug"}]

Here is the [Injector Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeGw8.png) if this helps.

//todo-item.component

```
onRemoveTodo() {
    this.remove.emit(this.todo);
}
```

//todo-list.component

```
removeTodo(todo: Todo) {
  this.TodoStoreService.remove(todo);
}
```

//todo-store.service

```
remove(todo: Todo) { 
/*this is where I need help*/
}
```

//storage.service

```
export class StorageService {
storage = window.localStorage;

has(name: string): boolean {
    return this.get(name) !== null;
}

get(name: string): any {
    const item = this.storage.getItem(name);

    try {
        return JSON.parse(item);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

set(name: string, value: any) {
    this.storage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));
}

remove(name: string) {
    this.storage.removeItem(name);
}
}
```

//todo

```
export class Todo {
private _completed = false;
private _title: string;

constructor(title: string, completed = false) {
    this._title = title;
    this._completed = completed;
}

get completed(): boolean {
    return this._completed;
}

get title(): string {
    return this._title;
}
set title(value: string) {
    this._title = value.trim();
}

toggle() {
    this._completed = !this._completed;
}
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem` will not work in this cases because all your TODOs are stored in the same item. I think you need to generate some id for them and this will be the public property. You can just generate GUID for each TODO and then for removal you just get all TODOs from localStorage, then iterate from them, remove by GUID and set the collection back. Comparing them by name will mean that the name should be unique. Usually it's better to have unique id.

Comment: Have you tried putting a setter on the property and gaining access to it that way? If you have access to the Todo class then you can access a public setter.

Comment: @ChrisSharp I've tried that. I got 'undefined'. Similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744461/why-is-undefined-returned-when-accessing-properties-of-a-typescript-object-in-an) but I am getting the data from child component, I am not sure how to properly inherit it.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh That's true! I was given the structure to fill out the functions so I was trying to find a solution without changing it but I think it's worth to communicate with the person who gave me the assignment!

Comment: Using `localStorage.removeItem` won't hurt :)
But you need some tricks

Comment: @M98 Do you mind telling me the tricks? :) Thanks!

Comment: get the value first, remove it from the received value, then add it to local storage